# JAVA get the value from one class to another

Tags: java

How can i get the value of string from class a to class b ?

```
public class A{
public String string = "A";
}

public class B{
public static void main(String []args){
   System.out.printl(string);
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate the class A and access the instance variable. Like this:

```
public class A{
    public String string = "A";
}

public class B{
    public static void main(String []args){
         A a = new A();
         System.out.println(a.string);
    }
}
```

**string** is an instance variable of class A.

Comment: public member variables cause so many issues that are painful to fix.

Comment: Agreed, and I think that no one should use like this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot have two public classes in the same file.

So I suggest that you move `class A` to `A.java` and leave the`class B` in `B.java`

```
A.java

public class A{
    public String string = "A";
}
```

B.java

```
public class B{
    public static void main(String []args){
         A a = new A();
         System.out.println(a.string);
    }
}
```

Upon invoking class `B`, a new object of class `A` would be create and the variable of `A` can be access through it.

Answer (score 0):

public access to member fields cause so many problems, fix them before you have them with a technique of hiding them behind a method.

```
public class A {

    public String getString() {
      return "A";
    }
}

public class B{
    public static void main(String []args){
         A a = new A();
         System.out.println(a.getString());
    }
}
```